# iMessage Freezes/Hangs when sending screen shots

Tags: messages, performance, kernel-panic

Worked fine sending 114k file of .png screen-shot; a 254k file freezes it dead.

So bad that I couldn't open up a tab in Safari. I suspect Evil Forces, but would be amused to learn it's a known issue.

Tested further just now sending 169k jpg file: hung so badly that again couldn't type here in Safari. Like it's sucking up all the good electrons and puppies.

Kernel panic? And why?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem just recently. Here is what I did.

follow this to fix the problem

~/Library/Preferences

delete com.apple.ichat.plist

Comment: Thought you nailed it with the plist suggesting, but there is no such file, nor an imessage.plist

Comment: ok, my messages was locking up. I deleted the ichat.plist! Don't ask why, I don't know how are they interrelated. copy the ~/Library/Preferences and paste in finders go to

Comment: Again, not seeing that in my preferences folder.

Comment: strange! you should find multiple iChatxxyy.plist files? are you on Mavericks?

Comment: Yes, 10.9.3. Not seeing any plists, per above.